# Why is my Android app Crashing?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, layout, tabs

My android app keeps crashing but there aren't any errors.
Heres the codes.

**LocationActivity.java** 
**UPDATED**

```
package com.marakana.tutomaps;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class LocationActivity extends TabActivity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec1, spec2, spec3;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent1, intent2, intent3;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent1 = new Intent().setClass(this, HaffActivity.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Haff").setIndicator("Haff",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_haff))
                  .setContent(intent1);
    tabHost.addTab(spec1);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent2 = new Intent().setClass(this, MapsActivity.class);
    spec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Maps").setIndicator("Maps",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_maps))
                  .setContent(intent2);
    tabHost.addTab(spec2);

    intent3 = new Intent().setClass(this, ProfileActivity.class);
    spec3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Profile").setIndicator("Profile",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_profile))
                  .setContent(intent3);
    tabHost.addTab(spec3);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
}
}
```

Here is the main layout file. **UPDATED**
**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"      android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0.5dip"
            android:background="#000" />
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip" android:layout_marginRight="0dip" />
        <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#696969" />
        <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#000" />
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Heres the manifest file **UPDATED**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.marakana.tutomaps"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".LocationActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
                    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

<activity android:name=".HaffActivity">
</activity>

<activity android:name=".MapsActivity">
</activity>

<activity android:name=".ProfileActivity">
</activity>

</application>
```

**MapsActivity.java**

```
   package com.marakana.tutomaps;

   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.util.List;

   import android.location.Address;
   import android.location.Geocoder;
   import android.location.Location;
   import android.location.LocationListener;
   import android.location.LocationManager;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.widget.TextView;

   import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
   import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
   import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
   import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

   public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity implements LocationListener {

private static final String TAG = "MapsActivity";

LocationManager locationManager;
Geocoder geocoder;
TextView locationText;
MapView map;    
MapController mapController;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    locationText = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.lblLocationInfo);
    map = (MapView)this.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    mapController = map.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(16);

    locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    geocoder = new Geocoder(this);

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (location != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, location.toString());
        this.onLocationChanged(location);   
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10, this);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged with location " + location.toString());
    // Displays lat, long, altitude and bearing
    String text = String.format("Lat:\t %f\nLong:\t %f\nAlt:\t %f\nBearing:\t %f", location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), location.getAltitude(), location.getBearing());
    this.locationText.setText(text);

    try {
        // This gets a list of addresses 
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 10);
        for (Address address : addresses) {
            this.locationText.append("\n" + address.getAddressLine(0));
        }

        // Convert latitude and longitude into int that the GeoPoint constructor can understand
        int latitude = (int)(location.getLatitude() * 1000000);
        int longitude = (int)(location.getLongitude() * 1000000);

        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(latitude,longitude);
        mapController.animateTo(point);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("LocateMe", "Could not get Geocoder data", e);
    }
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
   }
```

**Please help me.**

Comment: post logcat when your app crashes........

Comment: Try to run with Debug configuration (Eclipse) and see at Logcat windows (Debug perspective).

Comment: clean the project and run again

Comment: 09-21 12:59:16.900: ERROR/dalvikvm(2399): Could not find class 'com.marakana.tutomaps.MapsActivity', referenced from method com.marakana.tutomaps.LocationActivity.onCreate

Comment: For some reason it doesn't like this row:         intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MapsActivity.class);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you did one mistake...
You are passing Layout value instead of intent..

just check your code with mine.. you are passing **R.layout.hafflayout** instead of **intent** in **setContent(intent);** line

**Updated**

```
TabHost.TabSpec spec1,spec2,spec3;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
Intent intent1,intent2,intent3;
intent1 = new Intent().setClass(this, HaffActivity.class);

// Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Haff").setIndicator("Haff",
                  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_haff))
              .setContent(intent1);
tabHost.addTab(spec);

// Do the same for the other tabs
intent2 = new Intent().setClass(this, MapsActivity.class);
spec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Maps").setIndicator("Maps",
                  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_maps))
              .setContent(intent2);
tabHost.addTab(spec);

intent3 = new Intent().setClass(this, ProfileActivity.class);
spec3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Profile").setIndicator("Profile",
                  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_profile))
              .setContent(intent3);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

**Update:**

you didnt add dot(**.**) before activity's name in **menifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".HaffActivity">
</activity>

<activity android:name=".MapsActivity">
</activity>

<activity android:name=".ProfileActivity">
</activity>
```

**Update...Latest**

in your MapsActivity.class you setContentView(R.layout.main); so please change it and add your xml for MapActivity

Comment: yeap all of them looks like this execept of the name.

Comment: intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MapsActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Maps").setIndicator("Maps",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_maps))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

Comment: 09-21 12:59:16.900: ERROR/dalvikvm(2399): Could not find class 'com.marakana.tutomaps.MapsActivity', referenced from method com.marakana.tutomaps.LocationActivity.onCreate

Comment: Somehow it doesn't like this row:         intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MapsActivity.class);

Comment: still doesn't work, the only error i get in Logcat is: 09-21 13:06:30.810: ERROR/dalvikvm(2576): Could not find class 'com.marakana.tutomaps.MapsActivity', referenced from method com.marakana.tutomaps.LocationActivity.onCreate

Comment: 1)did you created all activity? 2) please use diff variable like as intent1, intent2, intent3, spec1,spec2,spec3 for diff tab..and check

Comment: what exactly do you mean? You mean profile?: spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Profile").setIndicator("Profile",

Comment: changed the specs and intents but still doesn't work. It seems like it doesn't find the mapsactivity.class

Comment: Theres something about this raw that the app doesn't like:         intent2 = new Intent().setClass(this, MapsActivity.class);

Comment: just clean your project and check........please update your question with latest class file, xml file, and menifest...

Comment: did you created MapActivity.java file?

Comment: I tested on both Motorola Xoom and Emulator with the same results.

Comment: finally if you got error seems like it doesn't find the mapsactivity.class  means your mapsactivity are not find out.. so plz check is it in same package? or just change mapsactivity.class to HaffActivity.class so we could check exactly where error comes

Comment: I maked this code to a comment, which made it all to work but WHY. // Do the same for the other tabs //intent2 = new Intent().setClass(this, MapsActivity.class); //spec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Maps").setIndicator("Maps", // res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_maps)) // .setContent(intent2); //tabHost.addTab(spec2);

Comment: it doesn't find the mapsactivity.class means your mapsactivity are not find out.. so plz check is it in same package?

Comment: Its in the same package, i added the MapsActivity.Java Code to the question, please take a look at it.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I get error: 09-21 13:54:13.858: ERROR/dalvikvm(3111): Could not find class 'com.marakana.tutomaps.MapsActivity', referenced from method com.marakana.tutomaps.LocationActivity.onCreate

Comment: write this line <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> in application Tag not in intent-filter Tag
 in your menifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Have you add to your `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".LoadingActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity> 

    <activity android:name="HaffActivity"
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="MapsActivity"
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="ProfileActivity"
    </activity>

</application>
```

Because if you have different activities in your project then you must add them in the manifest.

Comment: I edit my answer does your manifest looks like this now ? And when you run your app does it work now ? @downvoter : why downvote ?

Comment: Your Manifest looks ok, now try the answer of CapDroid.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the project. Also, are you using the google libraries for [maps](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html)? You need to add a link to Google API.

Comment: I got this in the manifest, is that enough?:            <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

Comment: Which libs are you using in your Android project? Can you try to execute that Activity by separate withtout the tab, And post the logcat?

Comment: Im using Android 1.6 and Google maps API. I don't really know what you mean, when i run the app the only error i get is: 09-21 13:09:57.200: ERROR/dalvikvm(2618): Could not find class 'com.marakana.tutomaps.MapsActivity', referenced from method com.marakana.tutomaps.LocationActivity.onCreate

Comment: I meant that the best to do is to separate the problem. So create a project only with yout MapsActivity. And post the error if you get one.Also you can try to specify the complete rute to you activity on the name of it eg. <activity android:name="com.marakana.tutomaps.MapsActivity"</activity>

Comment: I maked this code to a comment, which made it all to work but WHY.         // Do the same for the other tabs
        //intent2 = new Intent().setClass(this, MapsActivity.class);
        //spec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Maps").setIndicator("Maps",
        //                  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_maps))
        //              .setContent(intent2);
        //tabHost.addTab(spec2);

Comment: Cause your problem is in your activity MapsActivity, thats why is better for you to test it separately.